# Angular Defaults all $http requests to GET requests

Tags: angularjs, apache, http, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing an angular project with Laravel 5. I have been developing this locally and works absolutely fine. All requests translate properly.

eg. here is my code that sets the http method

```
var params = {
     url:opts.url,
     method:opts.method
};

params.params = data;

$http(params).success(function(){});
```

If my opts.method is GET it says its GET if its POST it says its POST.

As soon as I host it on my digital ocean droplet my opts.method is a POST or a DELETE or a PUT it will turn automatically turn to a GET request.

This is obviously a problem as I need to use POST and DELETE requests.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this would be failing?

While hosted on the server I console logged the params object

```
Object {url: "/api/update/", method: "POST", params: Object}
```

This still tried to send a GET request to the server.

I don't think it will be server side doing it as if i fake the requests its going through fine, and Laravel will return 405 method not allowed as soon as a GET request tries to go to a route that is made for POST requests.

Here are server details anyway, using Ubuntu running Apache2. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What if you used one of the shortcut methods?

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

or in your case:

```
$http[opts.method.toLowerCase()](...)
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

*disclaimer: I know that this doesn't answer the question but I don't have enough rep to comment yet.*

Comment: Yep tried that and it didnt work. I have just been going over it for about 5 hours. Just found out that it was laravel and trailing slashes.

Comment: Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: Ah what a pain! Glad you figured it out. Maybe edit the question to reflect the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was trailing slashes. In Laravel routes it was /api/update in angular I used /api/update/ which for some reason made angular use a get request.

As soon as I changed angular to match the trailing slashes of the Laravel routes. It worked fine.